# How to have one binary operation performed over a binary array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, boolean

Suppose a binary array `var arr = [true, true, false];`.

Is there any way to get the `AND` or `OR` of the whole array using one method?

Comment: What do you mean by `way to get the AND or OR of the whole array `. Tell us the final output and show us what you have already tried..

Comment: The operation to literally iterate the operation over an array would be `reduce`: `arr.reduce((a, b) => a && b)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [`Boolean`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Boolean) as callback for

- OR with [`Array#some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) or for
- AND  with [`Array#every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every).

```js
var array = [true, true, false];

console.log(array.some(Boolean));  // or
console.log(array.every(Boolean)); // and
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes: for `AND` you use [`arr.every(bool => bool)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every), for `OR` you use [`arr.some(bool => bool)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some).

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`every()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) for an AND:

```
arr.every(x => x);
```

And [`some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) for OR:

```
arr.some(x => x);
```